# Get collections from all the child objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented something like this:

```
class Move < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :move_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :move_categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :move_categories
  has_many :moves, through: :move_categories
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Category'
  has_many :subcategories, class_name: 'Category', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
end
```

So for a given a Category, I need to find the best way to get all my moves, and also all the ones from my sub-categories, and the ones from the sub-categories of my sub-categories, and so on.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:

Here's the MoveCategory model:

```
class MoveCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :move
  belongs_to :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :category_id, scope: :move_id
end
```

Comment: where is the `move_categories` table?

Comment: Are you using PostGreSQL by any chance?

Comment: So you want to find all the `moves` that belong to a `Category`? your question is not clear to me

Comment: No, I want to get, appart from my the moves from a given category, the moves from the child categories of that category. Is it clear now?

Comment: And yes @MrYoshiji I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: you want `the moves from the child categories of that category`. No Idea what that means. maybe an example would help.

Comment: Rhaa Come on Wali Ali! He has 1 Category, he wants to find its moves AND the moves of the Category's children!

Comment: A category has many categories (subcategories). Also the category has many moves. So given a category (let's say cat), I need to find a way to get all the moves from cat's subcategories, and also cat's moves. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using PostreSQL, you should take advantage of the `WITH RECURSIVE` CTE syntax to do this.  See http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/recursive-sql-in-activerecord for a great writeup.

If you implement the `tree` methods, all that's missing is the Move retrieval:

```
def Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def descendant_moves
    tree_id_sql = self.class.tree_sql_for(self)
    Move.joins(:move_categories).where("move_categories.category_id IN (#{tree_id_sql})")
  end
end
```

For completeness, here's the code for the `tree_sql_for` method from the above listed page:

```
def self.tree_sql_for(instance)
  tree_sql =  <<-SQL
    WITH RECURSIVE search_tree(id, path) AS (
        SELECT id, ARRAY[id]
        FROM #{table_name}
        WHERE id = #{instance.id}
      UNION ALL
        SELECT #{table_name}.id, path || #{table_name}.id
        FROM search_tree
        JOIN #{table_name} ON #{table_name}.parent_id = search_tree.id
        WHERE NOT #{table_name}.id = ANY(path)
    )
    SELECT id FROM search_tree ORDER BY path
  SQL
end
```